# What happens if I don't removeEventListener (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm adding some event listeners to check if it's a touch device or not. So I want the eventListeners present until the page is reloaded.

Should I still remove the event listeners ( `removeEventListener( 'touchstart', myFunction )`? And if so, why?

It's inside a VueJS-application, in the root-instance. I'm adding the event listeners inside the created-section.

Comment: If the page is truly reloaded, they're gone anyway.

Comment: If that's all you're using them for, removing them will prevent your function from unnecessarily having to execute every time they tap the screen during a pageview.

Comment: @Pointy I think OP means they want them to execute once at the start for a SPA.

Comment: @ceejayoz that may be true, but the term "SPA" is nowhere to be seen in the question

Comment: @Pointy Most Vue apps are SPAs.

Comment: OK that's fair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason you should remove event listeners before destroying the component which added them is because once your component is gone, the function that should be executed when the event happens is gone as well (in most cases) so, if the element you bound the listener to outlasts the component, when the event happens you'll get an error, as the code to be executed is nowhere to be found.

While this is most times an edge case, it tends to generate bugs which are particularly hard to debug.

On top of that, in a SPA (which is the most common usage of Vue applications) not removing listeners can quickly become a performance issue.

---

**Important note**: Only events you added yourself through DOM manipulation (e.g: `el.addEventListener()`) have to be removed. Vue cleans up after itself (`@click`, `@my-custom-event`, etc...).