# Is it necessary to removeeventlistener for addeventlistener and render2.listen in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

does anyone know is it necessary to remove listener for addeventlistener and render2.listen in Angular? I've always thought that after you leave a specific route, it's component is destroyed, removed from the DOM and the listeners are automatically removed. Or this is not the case? Maybe they are only removed when they are attached to an element of the component and in case they are attached to global objects like document and window they are not removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is the answer that I've got from Angular community:

I don't think there is any reason to worry about this situation.  If the nodes are in the DOM they still probably need the listeners. If the nodes are kept as references so they can be re-added to the DOM, then they probably still need the listeners. If the nodes are removed from the DOM and from the references then the listeners will also be garbage collected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you should remove event listeners before destroying the component which added them is because once your component is gone, the function that should be executed when the event happens is gone as well (in most cases) so, if the element you bound the listener to outlasts the component, when the event happens you'll get an error, as the code to be executed is nowhere to be found.

While this is most times an edge case, it tends to generate bugs which are particularly hard to debug.

On top of that, in a SPA not removing listeners can quickly become a performance issue.

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62865184/what-happens-if-i-dont-removeeventlistener-javascript)

Hope this help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Vivek, thank you very much for reply! I saw the original answer concerned Vue.js. But what about Angular? Does it really remove listeners automatically when the component is destroyed? Is there any sense to remove it on NgDestroy or not? In case of Observables you have to unsubscribe from them manually, but I am still confused about listeners(

Comment: Yes, Angular also follow same. Not always remove eventlisner on ngOnDestroy automatically. Specially for SPA this can be a performance issue. You can use Async pipe which no need to unsubscribe.Thanks!